# setToolbarItems issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I added toolbar to on screen of navigation based application using the following code

```
    //Create an array to hold the list of bar button items
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];


    //Add buttons

    //load the image
    UIImage *buttonImage ;


    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];



    //create the button and assign the image for window width and level
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(WWL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    WindowWidthZoom = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:button  ];
    [items addObject:WindowWidthZoom ];

    [self setToolbarItems:items];
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

but when leave the screen , I noticed that the toolbar didn't disappear in the other screens , any suggestion how to hide it before leaving this screen to avoid its presence in other screens , and how to change its color to black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add the following to the -viewWillAppear method of all your other view controllers:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

In the view controller where you want the toolbar to appear, make sure you setToolbarHidden to NO also in the -viewWillAppear method.  Doing so in the -viewDidLoad method is not enough because this method is not called every time a view appears.  For example, when you hit the Back button of a navigation controller and return to a previous view controller, since that view controller has already been loaded, it may not need to load again (and so -viewDidLoad will not be called.)

Comment: or just add this line of code to the -viewWillDisappear of your controller... its easier than add this line to all the other view controller's -viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your last line code:

```
 [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

to:

```
 [self setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

And make sure call it in:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```